# VBA to build blank Connection in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, connection

I am trying to build a blank SQL connection in Excel that will be updated with a connection string and command text a later point in the report.

Code I am trying to use:

`Workbooks("WorkBook1.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Test1", "Test1", " ", " ", "SQL"`

Syntax from Microsoft:

```
Add2 (string Name, string Description, object ConnectionString, object CommandText, object lCmdtype, object CreateModelConnection, object ImportRelationships);
```

However, I am struggling with the syntax as I keep getting errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not create the connection/string when you know where you're going to be connecting? Also, looks like you're missing two parameters.

Comment: sigh..right.  I actually have the connection built but for specifics of the report, I have to remove the connection.  when I remove the connection I want to also create a new blank connection that will be turned into the original connection with an updated connection string and command text.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't really an answer but rather a work around.

```
    Sub Add_Connection()

        Workbooks("WorkBook1.xlsm").Connections.AddFromFile _
            "C:\Document\template_Connection.odc"

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("template")
    .Name = "Facility"
    .Description = ""
    End With

End Sub
```

I have a saved connection on my computer that I add and rename.